# OpenBLAS in DLL hangs in FreeLibrary

Tags: c++, dll, lapack, blas

I don't know if there is a way to free OpenBLAS if it's used in a DLL, but when I load a DLL that uses OpenBLAS, and then tries to free it, the FreeLibrary function hangs (deadlock?) and never returns.

I use pre-built package downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.2.8/
compiling the test program with Visual Studio 2010.

Any ideas?

Here is code to reproduce the issue:

### Dummy DLL using OpenBLAS, does nothing:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cblas.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

void FunctionNeverCalled()
{
   float f = 1;
   cblas_sasum(1, &f, 1);
}
```

### Program calling the DLL:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   HINSTANCE hInstance = ::LoadLibraryExW(L"..\\Debug\\DllUsingOpenBlas.dll", NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
   ::FreeLibrary(hInstance); // Hangs on FreeLibrary
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And `hInstance` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Try to call `FunctionNeverCalled`. OpenBlas might try to finalize initialization never done.

Comment: Does OpenBLAS use openmp?  And if so is your test program built for it?

Comment: hInstance is not NULL and OpenBLAS is not built for openmp. I also tried to call the FunctionNeverCalled function, both from inside the DLL and from the test program, but still hangs on FreeLibrary. Thanks for the ideas anyhow! :)